# Checking existing element in database with Node.js and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

so here's the issue, everything inside the `con.query(query, function (err, result, fields)` is never called. So this is the part of code that is about verifying that when the user is signing up, the email that he took is not already taken. `argv[0]` contains the email that the user typed (it's not wrong, I debugged it). So I obviously created two accounts with the same email but the second one is never flagged (the function is continuing instead of returning "userexists").

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 

var con = mysql.createConnection(Credentials). //  The connection is established, it's not a problem.

var query = "SELECT id FROM accounts_data WHERE email = '" + argv[0] + "'";
var r;
con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
  if (err)
    return "failed";
  if(result != undefined) 
    return "userexists" // The if is never checked
});
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Hello everyone, so the `console.log(results.length)` is printing the right result, but how can I give the result to `r`? Because the last `console.log(r)` is still printing 0.

```
var r = 0;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM accounts_data WHERE email = ' + con.escape(argv[0]);
con.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) throw error;
console.log(results.length); // Right result
r = results.length; // Not giving the result to r
});
console.log(r); // Not the right result
```

Comment: I highly suggest you read `mysql`'s README section titled, [_Escaping query values_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values)...

Comment: use `con.query('SELECT id FROM accounts_data WHERE email = ?', [argv[0]], (err, res) => { ... })`

Comment: Given `query()` is asynchronous, you cannot `return` the results to anything. Also, you should be checking `result.length`

Comment: There are two things need to change. 1. return will not work inside the callback.  2. if the result is `null` then `result != undefined` will get false. So, you have to change the line to `if(result)`

Comment: Now I just can't assign my local variable to result

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Promise`'s, they'll help get away from 'callback-hell'

```js
const userExists = async emailAddress => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  con.query(`
     SELECT EXISTS(
       SELECT id FROM accounts_data WHERE email = ?
     );
    `,
    [emailAddress],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) { reject(err); }

      resolve(result);
    }
  )
);

await userExists('abc@example.com') // => boolean
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I'm still a beginner with JS (I coded with other languages I'm not 100% new). How can I retrieve the data returned by `await userExists('abc@example.com')`

Comment: `userExists('abc@example.com')` returns a promise, which can be accessed either by `userExists('abc@example.com').then(exists => { /* use it here*/ })`
or `const exists = await userExists('abc@example.com'); if (exists) { /* do something */ }`

but await can only be used inside of an async function

use this for reference; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise